# Send Email without storing or prompting for password

Tags: c#, winforms, email

I am building a Winform C# Desktop application for a client. I intend to include a  Contact form in the application through which  my client can contact me through the form. However I donot want to save the password in the application or prompt for the password from the client.

Any idea how I can do it. Any useful pointers in the same direction would help me a lot.

Comment: I can send email if I can save my password.

Comment: You mean you dont want to hardcode your password even inside the application? In that case I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use service(WCF or any other technology, it does not really matter) for sending notifications. In this case you will be able to add/modify it without updating client's application. And you don't need to store sensitive data in public application